# itkMRIBiasFieldCorrectionFilter wont run

Tags: itk

Did anyone use `itk::MRIBiasFieldCorrectionFilter` before?
It keeps on showing error of exception of memory on `filter->Update()`:

```
using FilterType = itk::MRIBiasFieldCorrectionFilter < ImageType, ImageType, MaskType >;

FilterType::Pointer filter = FilterType::New();

filter->SetInput(reader->GetOutput());

filter->Update();
```

I didn't input any parameters to this filter except input image from a .dcm file.
Reading in the .dcm file is 100% correct since it is successfully shown by QuickView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1MRIBiasFieldCorrectionFilter.html) for it says it is for 3D images, and you might be passing a 2D one.

You could also take a look at the no longer maintained [example application](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITKApps/tree/master/MRIBiasCorrection). It should work with ITK version 4.2, maybe up to 4.6 or 4.8.

Comment: Gracias, Very helpful!

Comment: Accept is as an answer then, and possibly up-vote it too :D

Comment: Sorry Dzenan, I tried to upvote but the system wont allow because my account level is low. I check-marked and accpeted this answer!! Gracias~~  Also I got a new ITK module question hoping you could answer it. Dos Gracias~~  https://stackoverflow.com/q/54434167/10313195